# Why can't I edit someone's question?

Tags: support

I wanted to edit [Additional jacking force to overcome stiction/dry friction](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/89/77) to add the new "friction" tag, but the edit button is grayed out.  Is this a bug, or is it a characteristic of the private beta, and if the latter could someone explain how editing is supposed to work at this stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't edit that question because there was already another edit pending approval and you have not gained enough reputation to perform edits without review.

As list of the things you can do against the reputation required to do more can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

n.b. as it's my question, I will add the friction tag.

Comment: I don't think that's right: I can edit questions everywhere else with just 100 rep, it's just that edits are held for review unless one has 2000.

Comment: You're right; there's an additional restriction on questions with pending edits. I've updated my answer to reflect this: we live and learn!